# Print a list in another function in Python

Tags: python

I want to print `myList` in `def b():`. I used the following code:

```
def a():
    myList = []
    name = myList.append(raw_input("my name"))
    return myList

def b():
    newList=a()
    print newList
```

But it isn't working. What do I need to change to be able to do this?

Comment: What's not working? Why are you trying to print it?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call `b()`?

Comment: So are you calling `b()` somewhere? Is the `raw_input()` call reached? What's happening?

Comment: What doesn't work? In it's current form this works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`"something"` is a string, not a list. However `["something"]` would be a list of 1 string.

Your code is basically working, just don't forget to call `b()` somewhere if you want to display the result.

**EDIT**:
Once again, it does work! Except that your're using raw input, so that you expect input from your user.

Run your b function, it will expect some input from your user : just type `Florent[return]`. your printed list will contain `['Florent']`

Most probably, you need to read some good book about generic programming then python before asking questions...

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
def a():
    myList = []
    name = myList.append(raw_input("my name"))
    b(myList)

def b(lst):
    newList=lst
    print newList

a()
```

Change "raw_input" to "input" for python3 and above.